# Visual Studio 2017 - Create DLL from Only Static Libs (No sources)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, dll, visual-studio-2017

We have a visual studio project to produce a DLL file, and we've now refactored all the sources out into 3 separate projects which produce static libs. This leaves behind the `.def` file, and some pre and post-build actions related to the dll itself in this project. We'd like to keep the generation of the DLL and all the additional behavior separate from the other projects if we can.

Unfortunately, now when we try to "build" this project, it does not produce a DLL anymore (presumably because there are no sources that reference any of the libs).

I've added `/WHOLEARCHIVE:themainstaticlib`, but that doesn't seem to be enough.

If it's possible to have a Visual Studio project that JUST creates a DLL from static libs and a def file (and a `/wholearchive` directive), can someone please let me know how?